# Skaffold Yaml Volume Format

Tags: skaffold

I have a skaffold yaml using v2beta26 api schema. In this config I'm trying to define my buildpack configuration like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta26
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: service
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: service-api
    buildpacks:
      builder: paketobuildpacks/builder:base
      volumes: 
        - "./java/maven/binding:/platform/bindings/my-maven-settings"
```

However, when I run: `skaffold build` I keep getting this message about the format:

```
cannot unmarshal !!str `./java/...` into v1.BuildpackVolume
```

The volumes section seems to be wrong but I need this to mount our maven settings for a private repo. I checked the schema docs, but there's no examples or format indicator at all. I'm clearly not formatting this correctly, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The `buildpacks.volumes` maps to a [`BuildpackVolume`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/bfb56aa31749e9a7364e95cc330a580211eebe57/pkg/skaffold/schema/latest/v1/config.go#L1058-L1073) and looks something like:

```
   - image: skaffold-buildpacks
     buildpacks:
       builder: "gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1"
       trustBuilder: true
       volumes:
       # host is the local directory or a volume name
       # target is the mount point in the container
       # options is "ro" for read-only, "rw" for read-write
       - host: skaffold-buildpacks-cache
         target: /skbpcache
         options: "rw"
       env:
       - GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION=8
       - GOOGLE_BUILD_ARGS=-Dmaven.repo.local=/skbpcache
```

The [Cloud Code](https://cloud.google.com/code) plugins for VS Code and IntelliJ include validation and auto-complete support for `skaffold.yaml`.